# Snowflake Python Pandas Connector - Unknown error using fetch_pandas_all

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to connect to snowflake using the python pandas connector.

I use the anaconda distribution on Windows, but uninstalled the existing connector and pyarrow and reinstalled using instructions on this page: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector-pandas.html

I have the following versions

> pandas                    1.0.4            py37h47e9c7a_0
>
> pip                       20.1.1                   py37_1
>
> pyarrow                   0.17.1                   pypi_0    pypi
>
> python                    3.7.7                h81c818b_4
>
> snowflake-connector-python 2.2.7                    pypi_0    pypi

When running step 2 of this document: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector-install.html, I get: 4.21.2

On attempting to use `fetch_pandas_all()` I get an error: NotSupportedError: Unknown error

[image]

The code I am using is as follows:

```
import snowflake.connector
import pandas as pd

SNOWFLAKE_DATA_SOURCE = '<DB>.<Schema>.<VIEW>'

query = '''
select * 
from table(%s)
LIMIT 10;
'''
def create_snowflake_connection():
    conn = snowflake.connector.connect(
            user='MYUSERNAME',
            account='MYACCOUNT',
            authenticator = 'externalbrowser',
            warehouse='<WH>',
            database='<DB>',
            role='<ROLE>',
            schema='<SCHEMA>'
    )
    
    return conn

con = create_snowflake_connection()

cur = con.cursor()
temp = cur.execute(query, (SNOWFLAKE_DATA_SOURCE)).fetch_pandas_all()
cur.close()
```

I am wondering what else I need to install/upgrade/check in order to get `fetch_pandas_all()` to work?

**Edit**:  After posting an answer below, I have realised that **the issue is with the SSO (single sign on)** with authenticator='externalbrowser'.  When using a stand-alone account I can fetch.

Comment: Did you look at the example in the Snowflake documentation? https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector-api.html#fetch_pandas_all This might just be an issue of format of the query string.

Comment: Yes, same error.

Comment: Running `show parameters like '%python_connector_query_result_format%'` returns value Arrow, and ROWS_PER_RESULTSET is 0.

Comment: To rule out packages and environments influenced by Anaconda, have you tried to use the libraries directly installed (outside of anaconda) via `pip3`?

Answer (score 13):

I found a workaround that avoids the SSO error by relying on fetchall() instead of fetch_all_pandas():

```
try: 
    cur.execute(sql)
    all_rows = cur.fetchall()
    num_fields = len(cur.description)
    field_names = [i[0] for i in cur.description]
finally:
    cur.close()

con.close()

df = pd.DataFrame(all_rows)
df.columns = field_names
```

Comment: Thanks, I always prefer to avoid another extra dependency if I can help it. This is similar to "df.columns = cur.keys()" used with other SQL connectors.

Answer (score 6):

The reason is snowflake-connector-python does not install "pyarrow" which you need to play with pandas.

Either you could install and Import Pyarrow or

Do :

pip install "snowflake-connector-python[pandas]"

and try it .

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Did the command you mention i am still getting the same error

Answer (score 1):

What happens when you run this code?

```html
from snowflake import connector
import time

import logging
for logger_name in ['snowflake.connector', 'botocore', 'boto3']:
    logger = logging.getLogger(logger_name)
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    ch = logging.FileHandler('test.log')
    ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    ch.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(threadName)s %(filename)s:%(lineno)d - %(funcName)s() - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'))
    logger.addHandler(ch)

from snowflake.connector.cursor import CAN_USE_ARROW_RESULT

import  pyarrow
import pandas as pd

print('CAN_USE_ARROW_RESULT', CAN_USE_ARROW_RESULT)
```

This will output whether CAN_USE_ARROW_RESULT is true and if it's not true, then pandas won't work.  When you did the pip install, which of these did you run?

pip install snowflake-connector-python
pip install snowflake-connector-python[pandas]

Also, what OS are you running on?

Comment: Thank-you for your help.  `CAN_USE_ARROW_RESULT` returns True.  I used the following to install:  pip install snowflake-connector-python[pandas].  The OS is: Windows 10 Pro.

Comment: I've tested the same on windows with the same problem. Apparently it won't work on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

I have this working now, but am not sure which part helps - the following steps were taken:

1. Based on comment by @Kirby, I tried `pip3 install --upgrade snowflake-connector-python` .. this is based on a historic screenshot .. I should have have [pandas] in brackets, i.e. `pip3 install --upgrade snowflake-connector-python[pandas]`, but regardless, I got the following error message:

> Error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required.  Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads

I therefore downloaded (exact filename: vs_buildtools__121011638.1587963829.exe) and installed VS Build Tools.

2. This is the tricky part .. I subsequently got admin access to my machine (so hoping it is the visual studio build tools that helped, and not admin access)
3. I then followed the Snowflake Documentation [Python Connector API](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector-api.html#label-python-connector-api-fetch-pandas-all) instructions originally referred to:

   a.  Anaconda Prompt (opened as *admin*): `pip install snowflake-connector-python[pandas]`

   b.  Python:

```
import snowflake.connector
import pandas as pd

ctx = snowflake.connector.connect(
          user=user,
          account=account,
          password= 'password',
          warehouse=warehouse,
          database=database,
          role = role,
          schema=schema)

# Create a cursor object.
cur = ctx.cursor()

# Execute a statement that will generate a result set.
sql = "select * from t"
cur.execute(sql)

# Fetch the result set from the cursor and deliver it as the Pandas DataFrame.
df = cur.fetch_pandas_all()
```

**Edit**  I have since realised that I still have the error when executing `df = cur.fetch_pandas_all()` when using my Okta (single sign on) account, i.e. when I use my username and authenticator = 'externalbrowser'.   When I use a different account, I no longer get the error (with password).
NOTE: That I am still able to connect with externalbrowser (and I see the query has executed successfully in Snowflake history); I am just not able to fetch.

Comment: as per edit here and in question; the issue remains when using SSO.  With SSO, I am able to execute the query successfully but not fetch to Python.  With a stand-alone account, I am successfully able to pull the data to Python using `fetch_pandas_all()`

Comment: Any solution to the above? with SSO fetching data

Answer (score 0):

Using ..

```
python -m pip install "snowflake-connector-python[pandas]"
```

..as in the docs did not fetch the correct version of pyarrow for me (docs says you need 3.0.x). 
With my conda (using python 3.8) I had to manually update pyarrow to the specifiv version:

```
python -m pip install pyarrow=6.0
```